# How to get the previous selected value for select list in visaulforce page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, selectlist

`<apex:selectOption itemvalue="Reports" itemLabel="select Report" />
                 <apex:selectOption itemvalue="1" itemLabel="Test1"/>
                 <apex:selectOption itemvalue="2" itemLabel="Test2"/>

            </apex:selectList>`
 I select the value 1 first, how do I retrieve the value of 1 after I choose 2 in visualforce page

Comment: Can any have idea about it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onfocus` attribute of `selectList` component for storing current value of picklist before choosing the new one in some JS variable and `onselect` or `onchange` attributes of `selectList` for processing of new and old values.

```
<apex:selectList value="{!test}" onfocus="storeOldValue(this.value)">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!testOptions}"/>
</apex:selectList>

<script type="text/javascript">
function storeOldValue(oldValue){
    oldVal = oldValue;
}
</script>
```